# Only one event when clicking label with input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want 1 event instead of 2 every time I click my `label`

Is it possible without selecting the input itself `document.querySelector('label input')` or/and with CSS only?

Run the example below and check the snippet console while switching between the two steps to see the 2 events.

```js
document.querySelector('label:first-of-type').onclick = e => console.log(e.target)
document.querySelector('label:last-of-type').onclick = e => console.log(e.target)
```

```css
label {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: grey;
  font-size: large;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=radio]:checked ~ * {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="step"><span>Step 1</span></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="step"><span>Step 2</span></label>
```

Comment: I don't understand what result are you after and under what condition.

Comment: I want 1 event instead of 2 every time I click

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector('label:first-of-type').onclick = e => console.log(e.target)
document.querySelector('label:last-of-type').onclick = e => console.log(e.target)

document.querySelectorAll('label span').forEach(el => el.onclick = e => e.stopPropagation() )
document.querySelectorAll('label input').forEach(el => el.onclick = e => e.stopPropagation() )
```

```css
label {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: grey;
  font-size: large;
border:1px solid;
padding:10px;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=radio]:checked ~ * {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="step"><span>Step 1</span></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="step"><span>Step 2</span></label>
```

Comment: Thank you Ashley but I still have 2 events and I want only one

Comment: But thats because you have no label content, it's always going to be unreliable because you've nested elements in it. I've updated the code to prevent the inner elements bubbling, but its not reliable because you have to click in exactly the right place e.g around the text (i added padding to demonstrate). Why not just put the event on the span given that the input is display none? The span is ultimately what you're clicking on

Comment: Yes, but it that case we are selecting the `input` and using more JavaScript. I tried also `pointer-events: none` but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you may want to add ids and use querySelector this way:

HTML:

```
<label><input id='first' type="radio" name="step"><span>Step 1</span></label
<label><input id='last' type="radio" name="step"><span>Step 2</span></label>
```

JS:

```
document.querySelector('#first').onclick = e => console.log(e.target)
document.querySelector('#last').onclick = e => console.log(e.target)
```

Comment: but that's like selecting the input at the end `document.querySelector('#first')` = `document.querySelector('label input')`

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, try what @Ashley Brown commented in his/her post and use what you wrote about `pointer-events` to avoid the same event once and again if it's already checked.

```js
document.querySelector('label:first-of-type span').onclick = e => console.log(e.target)
document.querySelector('label:last-of-type span').onclick = e => console.log(e.target)
```

```css
label {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: grey;
  font-size: large;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=radio]:checked ~ * {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="step"><span>Step 1</span></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="step"><span>Step 2</span></label>
```

Hope this helps or at least points you to the right direction : )